# How do I parse HTML using Enliven?

Tags: clojure, enlive

Here is a parsing [example](https://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial/blob/master/src/tutorial/scrape1.clj) using Enlive. Would there be differences with [Enliven](https://github.com/cgrand/enliven)?

```
(ns parse.enlive
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(def ^:dynamic *base-url* "https://news.ycombinator.com/")

(defn fetch-url [url]
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))

(defn hn-headlines []
  (map html/text (html/select (fetch-url *base-url*) [:td.title :a])))

(defn hn-points []
  (map html/text (html/select (fetch-url *base-url*) [:td.subtext html/first-child])))

(defn print-headlines-and-points []
  (doseq [line (map #(str %1 " (" %2 ")") (hn-headlines) (hn-points))]
    (println line)))
```

If there are not much differences in that simple example, where would Enliven be different when doing some web scraping?

Thanks!